# Jackson returning JSON hashmap with keywords 'entry','key' and 'value' in API response

Tags: jackson, jax-rs

I have written an API using jax-rs. The library I am using for JSON output is jackson. I have included its dependencies of data-bind, core and annotations for version 2.9.6. However my json response for a hashmap has keywords 'entry', 'key' and 'value' in it. How do I avoid those keywords in the response ?

I have tried using different versions of the dependencies.

Actual Response

```
{
    "hmap": {
        "entry": [
            {
                "key": "name",
                "value": "sebin"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Expected Response

```
{
    "hmap": {
        "name": "sebin"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use a custom deserializer?

Comment: I get that response when I hit the API on postman. It works as expected in springboot though.

Comment: "I get that response when I hit the API on postman. It works as expected in springboot though." Can you elaborate a bit more on it works as expected in spring boot

Comment: I meant, in an API of springboot project, if I have a hashmap as one of the members of the response class, then its JSON on postman appears as the ‘expected response’. That is to say the words entry, key, value do not appear.

Comment: Is there any annotation that I am missing in jax-rs? Or could someone verify if 2.9.8 is the latest version for jackson-databind?

Comment: Could you create a simple test where you can just serialise `Map` directly by `Jackson` and see the result? It should work properly by default. In your case probably another tool serialises object to `JSON`.

Comment: I suspected that as well. So I commented out the moxy dependency from the pom file. Within the code, if I convert an object to json string, the serialization works as expected. It is in the API response that the keywords appear.

Comment: Class jsonProvider = Class.forName("org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature");
            classes.add(jsonProvider);                                                                   
                                                                                                                         
 This worked. I added the above class in my application class.

Comment: Most likely, Jackson is not the JSON provider being used to serialize the entity. My guess is MOXy. If you have jersey-media-moxy, remove it. Make sure you have jersey-media-json-jackson and register the JacksonFeature with the application so it have priority over any other providers you may have, either explicitly or implicitly.

Comment: There is one other problem now. Jackson serializes all fields to null by default if it cannot find a match. I know that we can use the not null annotation but I can't now manually add the annotation to all classes. Can someone tell me a quick fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody was able to accurately answer this, I am posting the fix myself.

1. I added JacksonFeature.class to the set of classes in my
   application.
2. I also added a custom json mapper into it

Read Section 9.1.4 of the following [documentation](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson)